# c++ cout vs printf()

Tags: c++, printf, cout

After learning about c++ through a couple different sources, I found conflicting advice concerning the use of `cout`/`printf()`. One source said that `printf()`, and I quote:

> ... does not provide type safety, so it is easy to inadvertently tell it to display an integer as if it were a character and vice versa. printf() also does not support classes, and so it is not possible to teach it how to print your class data; you must feed each class member to printf() one by one.

So, the more important thing to me would be the readability factor of using printf(). On the other hand, another source mentioned that `cout`, with its use of the overloaded operator `<<`, uses more instructions to execute and can therefore be more expensive in terms of memory over a large program. Although, the person who said this was a systems programmer, in which every bit of performance is vital. But say I wanted to go into game or application development.

- Would the performance differences between `printf()` and `cout` matter all that much?
- In general, does it really matter what I choose to use in an application program?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Preferences are off-topic.

Comment: It's true about the type-safety, but about the instruction count? That msay be true *or* it may be false.

Comment: Please do some measures yourself and bring up provement in your question, instead of reporting from hearsay.

Comment: Voting to close for being opinion-based. In *pure* [tag:c++], you'd never use std C library functions like `printf()`, they are just accessible for compatibility with [tag:c]. Still there *might* be reasons to do so anyways, as outlined in the question. But after all, it comes down to 1.) your concrete problem and 2.) opinion.

Comment: Instruction count is irrelevant. What really matters is I/O. If you want performance, you should consider an asynchronous solution. If you have some high performance library logging stuff to stdout or a file, you do not want a blocking solution

Comment: C does not have `cout`&co, so this question is useless for C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would measure the differences on your particular implementation for your specific use case and determine that for yourself.

I would say both lines of reasoning in the question have merit, but you can't generalise about performance.

Comment: Ya that seems to be the general consensus here. Thanks.

Comment: To add to what this answer says: The time taken to format data is usually dwarfed by the time IO takes, you shouldn't care too much about computational efficiency in an IO bound problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go into game or application programming, printf/cout won't be needed too much. The only use in these cases is for debugging.

If you really need to use printf/cout a lot, the difference will be when writing a huge amount of data, otherwise you don't need to bother.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input!